# In which order are Interceptors excecuted?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, interceptor

I am reading some tutorials regarding `Interceptors` in java ee, but there are some themes which are not covered extensively. Therefore I would be greatful to anyone having answers to the following questions:

1) In which order are Interceptors execueted in case the target class contains an `@AroundInvoke` method as:

```
@Interceptors({PrimaryInterceptor.class, SecondaryInterceptor.class})
@Stateful
public class OrderBean {
...
    @AroundInvoke
    private void last(InvocationContext ctx) { ... }
...
}
```

I have the impression that first it is excecuted the taget class Interceptor, namely the `last` method in the above case and then the two class-level Interceptors in the order specified inside the annotation. Am I right?

2) What are `Timeout Interceptors` (containing methods with the annotation `@AroundTimeout`) and when are the excecuted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB3_Interceptors.html).

By default the ordering of interceptors when invoking a method are

- External interceptors
- Default interceptors, if present
- Class interceptors, if present
- Method interceptors, if present
- Interceptor method on the bean class (using `@AroundInvoke`)

Within each group (default, class, method) the order of the interceptors are from left to right as defined in the `@Interceptors` annotation, and then the `XML` interceptors.

And for the second question - `@AroundTimeout` is used together with EJB timers, interceptor is fired whenever method annotated with `@Schedule` timeouts - see this [example.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkedm.html)

Comment: this documentation say that "... and then the XML interceptors. " which means the order is annotations then XML.
why I can't find that in the interceptor spec (I think this is only the documentation of Jboss which may differ from other documentation)?